# How do I run a jar file in multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, jar

I need to run an executable JAR file in multiple threads/cores. The JAR file does not implement Runnable. I've been looking for a way to do that and haven't found one. Is it possible to make a JAR file use multiple threads/cores without having access to the source code?

Currently. if I just run the JAR file normally, it only uses a single core.

Comment: Jar files contain java classes and other resources.  A Jar is not a Java class and therefore cannot "implement Runnable".  Please edit your question and take a step back and provide background on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to magically make a program (doesn't matter if it's packaged in a Java JAR file or some other way) automatically use multiple cores. The program must have been written to make use of multiple cores - there's no other way.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. You can run several `java` processes running the same JAR in different threads, but this might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the jar is an executable jar, then it has a main method (the main class is listed in the manifest of the jar file).  you can invoke this main method in your own Runnable instance.

however, if the classes in this jar make use of static resources without appropriate synchronization, then this strategy won't work.  if this is the case, you could setup a separate ClassLoader per Runnable and run each instance of the jar in its own isolated ClassLoader (you would then need to invoke the main method using reflection).